# how can I bind datagridview column to tooltip.text using gmap.net

Tags: c#, tooltip, markers, gmap.net

I have a datagridview which have client name lat,long. I am able to point out all markers on map from datagridview but I want to display client name on marker tootltip text.

```
 while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string Latitude = myReader["Latitude"].ToString();
                    string Longitude = myReader["Longitude"].ToString();
                    gMapControl1.Position = new PointLatLng(float.Parse(Latitude), float.Parse(Longitude));
                    GMarkerGoogle marker = new GMarkerGoogle(gMapControl1.Position, GMarkerGoogleType.red);
                    markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
                    gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);
                    marker.ToolTip = new GMapRoundedToolTip(marker);
                   marker.ToolTipText = this.dataGridView1.Columns[4].ToString;

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this method to display name. You have already given the tooltiptext so you only need this:

```
marker.ToolTipMode = MarkerTooltipMode.Always;
marker.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(21,21);
marker.Offset = new System.Drawing.Point(-10,-10);
marker.ToolTip.Font = new Font("Arial",9,FontStyle.Bold);
```